# base_url in a .JS format

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have this code in my script.js:

```
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#uploadimage").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#message").empty();
        $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_upload_img_item.php", // Url to which the request is send
            type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as                                                 method
            data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value         pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
            contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to         the server.
            cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
            processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data         file it is set to false
            success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
            {    
                $('#loading').hide();
                $("#message").html(data);
            } 
        });
    }));
```

I want to load the ajax_upload_img_item.php BUT it wont work because i dont have the base_url(); command on it. And i cant add it on the script. How will I add the base_url(); command from the Codeigniter config, to the script.js? thank you

Comment: You need to make a global variable for base path in header and then you can access it in your js file. Let me know if you need more explanation

Comment: yeah, i dont really understand what you are talking about base path global variable thing, im new to the language actually sorry

Comment: Is `ajax_upload_img_item.php` in a different location compared to your `script.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the header of your page try to do this:

```
<header>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var base_url = "<?= base_url() ?>";
 </script>
</header>
```

Then in your .js file url becomes

```
url: base_url + "ajax_upload_img_item.php", // Url to which the request is sent
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it like this

```
<header>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var BASE_URL= "<?php echo base_url() ?>";
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>your_resource_folder_path/script.js"></script>
</header>
```

In script.js file

```
 url: BASE_URL+ "ajax_upload_img_item.php",
```